# ¿Cómo ejecutar procesos en segundo plano en Android?

Tags: java, android

Hasta dónde he investigado en un Activity se pueden usar los siguientes métodos en su ciclo de vida.

- onCreate()
- onStart()
- onResume()
- onPause()
- onStop()
- onDestroy()
- onRestart()

Pero todavía no he entendido si en alguno de ellos debo poner mi código (Hilos) que quiero que se ejecute en segundo plano o sí debería de ir en otra parte.

Comment: Sería bueno si podrías elaborar un poco que tareas quieres correr en segundo plano, si van a necesitar un hilo propio y una idea que intentas hacer con tu app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que la aplicación se ejecute en segundo plano debes de utilizar un "Servicio", y para poder utilizar hilos sin bloquear el hilo principal de la aplicación deberías de usar "AsyncTask"