# proceso se detiene al pasarlo a segundo plano

Tags: android

hola tengo un programa que tiene un proceso muy pesado durante el cual se muestra una barra de progreso. El problema es que cuando paso el programa a segundo plano (utilizando el boton redondo de android) la barra de progreso se detiene. Luego cuando paso la aplicacion a primer plano otra vez, vuelve a reanudarse. Entonces queria saber si hay algun modo de que la app no se detenga al pasarla a segundo plano. Por cierto ya he desactivado el "Ahorro de bateria en aplicaciones" y sigue igual. El codigo que muestro es una version minima de mi programa real, donde se puede reproducir la situacion.
Un saludo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(10000000);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new MyTask().execute(10);
            }
        });
    }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            
            for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            {
                progressBar.setProgress(i);
            }

            return "Task Completed.";
        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            //txt.setText("Running..."+ values[0]);
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo ejecutar procesos en segundo plano en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45295/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-procesos-en-segundo-plano-en-android)

Comment: No puedes modificar la UI directamente en `doInBackground`. Debes llamar la función `publishProgress` para que el código en `onProgressUpdate` lo haga.

Comment: gracias Mateo, me sirvio. Pero observo que al pulsar el boton redondo y pasarla a segundo plano, va mas lenta. ¿es normal?

Comment: Es muy importante saber que error obtienes, siempre agrega el error mostrado en el logcat, de otra forma las causas de cierre pueden ser muchas, saludos.